# emacs command to append to ring

Tags: emacs, copy, append

How can I make an emacs command to copy text (to the kill ring) by appending? (Why is there no such built-in command?)

[Appending Kills](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/info2www?(emacs)Appending%20Kills) mentions C-M-w (`append-next-kill') which allows me to append with kill commands such as C-d or C-k. But it's for killing texts instead of copying them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, there is such a built in command.  `C-M-w` will append a subsequent copy as well as a kill.  So you would mark the region you desire to copy, then type `C-M-w` followed by `M-w` and the next `C-y` will yank the joined kills.

Answer (score 4):

Play with a variation of this in your .emacs file...

```
(defun append-kill-line (&optional arg)
  "Append kill-line to current kill buffer, prefix arg kills from beginning of line."
  (interactive "P")
  (append-next-kill)
  (kill-line arg)
)

(define-key global-map "\C-x\C-m" 'append-kill-line)
```

Answer (score 2):

Can append-to-register meet your needs?

Answer (score 1):

The various kill commands use a little trick to decide whether or not to append.  If the previous command is the same as the current command, it will append; if not, it doesn't.  The functions use the value of `last-command` to do this, and manipulating this value is key to getting what you want.

```
(defun copy-region-as-kill-append (beg end)
  (interactive "r")
  (let ((last-command 'kill-region))
    (copy-region-as-kill beg end)))
```